# Complex and fast update in spring data jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a entity named `Product`. It has several fields and user can update one or more fields of it arbitrarily. For updating `Product`s, I know I can get persisted product from DB and update it fields and `save` it again, but this cause real performance penalty. The better way is to create custom update queries in `ProductRepostory` interface, but in this case I should write multiple update functions for each scenario. I want to get a `Map<String,Object>` of updating fields and their values, and write a query to update theme proportionally.

I heard that Hibernate has ability to create custom update query and execute like code below

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class OrderManagement {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    ...

    public void updateOrder(Double oldAmount, Double newAmount) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();

        // create update
        CriteriaUpdate<Order> update = cb.
        createCriteriaUpdate(Order.class);

        // set the root class
        Root e = update.from(Order.class);

        // set update and where clause
        update.set("amount", newAmount);
        update.where(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(e.get("amount"), oldAmount));

        // perform update
        this.em.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

But I'm wondering how to use this in spring data jpa circumstances, The biggest question is how to get entityManager instance, and next one is where is the most appropriate place to put this functionality? `ProductRepostory` interface or some custom interface, And if answer is custom interface, how to register it?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/add-custom-functionality-to-a-spring-data-reposito

You can find the custom repository in Spring Data in the above link.

Comment: Also Entity manager can be injected like this.  

   `@PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;`

Comment: 1. you don't need to save it again: Hibernate does that for you. 2. No this doesn't cause any real performance penalty. Reading a row in a table by its ID is extremely fast. You're optimizing prematurely, which is the root of all evil. Your code will become much more complex and less safe for an imaginary performance gain.

Comment: @JBNizet I must say I'm a big fan of you. 
Are you saying that everytime that I update an entity's field, hibernate persist it automatically? without calling `save`? Is this default behavior or must enable it manually?

Comment: Yes, this is the default behavior, and you don't need to do anything about it. Managed entities (i.e. entities that you've persisted inside a transaction, or obtained using the entity manager, or using a JPQL query, or by navigating through associations of other managed entities) are... managed by JPA. Their state is inspected and, if it has changed, JPA saves it in the DB when it needs to (before commit, or before a query whose result might be influenced by the new state).

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for clarifications, so until now I was torturing myself by writing complex and useless update queries!

Answer (score 0):

OK, The main reason to ask this question was a wrong hypothesis that I thought fetching and updating an entity in program may cause performance issues, But as @JBNizet has mentioned, fetching an entity by id is fast, and also Hibernate handles persisting changes on Entity and there is no need to call `save` manually.

So as nutshell, **PROPOSING NEW METHODS OF SAVING MANAGED ENTITIES IS NOT HELPFUL, AND IT'S BETTER TO AVOID UPDATE ENTITY MANUALLY**, but if one wants to extend Jpa Repositories manually, there is [nice article](https://dzone.com/articles/add-custom-functionality-to-a-spring-data-reposito) that explain it as have been mentioned in comments.